# Spring MVC Response already committed Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

`@RequestMapping(value="/getStats/{requestData}" ,` `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , method=RequestMethod.GET)`

```
public void testRequest(
@PathVariable (value="requestData") GetStatsRequestBean getStats){
       System.out.println("inside (testRequest)");
       System.out.println(getStats);
}
```

In server log am getting

SRTServletRes W   WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.

And my app url is..

```
http://myhost:9080/myapp/getStats/{"startDate":"2013-10-05","endDate":"2013-10-05"}
```

Comment: For Json dont use PathVariable. try to use RequestParam

Comment: Used the RequestParam as well and same result

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set a response header after the response is committed causes this warning. The code you shared does not seem to do this. Are you sure you do not have any filter configured which tries to do this ? Your controller handler method return type is void which implies that you intend to generate the response yourself by using http servlet response object which needs to be provided in tehemethod parameter so that Spring can inject it and you can use this. As you have not provided the httpservlet response object in parameter, the actual view served would be implicitly determined by through a RequestToViewNameTranslator configured in your context.

Comment: Even without void but with String as a reponse am getting same error